# Clarification on "restriction of a function" in two variables

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, optimization

I'm not getting the meaning of the text of the following exercise:

> be $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ defined as $f(x, y) = (y-x^2)(y-3x^2)$.

> Verify that the restrictions of $f$ to the straight lines of the bundle passing through the origin have a local minimum at $(0, 0)$

> Prove then that $f$ has not a local minimum at $(0, 0)$. Hint: study $f(a, 2a^2)$ and $f(0, b)$.

- I don't get the "restrictions" part. I mean the straight lines for the origin have equation $y = kx$ for $k$ real not zero. I tried to study $f(x, y)$ with $y = kx$ but I don't know if this is the right way to proceed.

I suspect it's an optimisation problem, but in case we did not study Lagrange multipliers yet.

- In the second question, I don't get the hint. Why shall I study that function in those points? Where do they come from?

Comment: A _restriction_ of a function is essentially the same function, except that its domain is a subset of the original function's domain.

Answer (score 2):

The only problem with looking at $y = kx$ is that it does not capture the behavior for lines coincident with the $y$-axis.  You could of course break this into two cases if you would like, but my recommendation would be to consider a parametrization for lines through the origin, like $x(t) = t x_0, y(t) = t y_0$ (where at least one of $x_0, y_0$ is nonzero).  So, consider $f(x(t), y(t))$ and its derivatives with respect to $t$ as $t \rightarrow 0$.

For the second question, consider the two curves $(a, 2a^2)$, $(0, b)$ for varying values of $a,b$ respectively (they are defined for all real $a,b$).  The first curve is a parabola, the other a vertical straight line (check if you feel like).  To show that we do not have a minimum we can check the limit of $f(a, 2a^2), f(0,b)$ and their derivatives (w.r.t $a,b$) as $a \rightarrow 0$ and $b \rightarrow 0$ (ie. as we approach the origin along those curves).  If there is a disagreement between these limits you can conclude that the point at the origin is not a minimum.

Comment: I did not understand the first point. After the parametrisation, I obtained a function in $t$. Both the derivative and the function go to zero for $t\to 0$, so $x_0$ and $y_0$ are free. How this tell me the minimum is at $(0, 0)$?

Comment: Doing the calculations it results that $f'(t)$ is zero for three values of $t$, one of which is zero. Yet it will be a max if we run the analysis by studying when $f'(t) > 0$, not a minimum...

Comment: Since the derivative goes to $0$ you have a critical point. Check the higher order derivatives of this function in order to determine whether or not it is a minimum for the lines through the origin, or just look at the sign of the derivative for various $t$. I just did the calculation myself and you can check that we get a minimum for all values of $x_0, y_0$. So we do indeed have a minimum for lines through the origin. Also, note that we only care about when $t \rightarrow 0$ because we are checking the function and derivatives at the origin, not any other point(s).

Comment: I don't obtain different derivatives in the second case. Both the function go to zero when $a\to 0$ and $b\to 0$ and the same for their derivatives...

Comment: Notice that for the vertical line (parametrized by $b$) we have what we found in the previous case, because it's a special example of the first part of the problem, ie. we have a minimum.  Check the parabolic curve parametrized by $a$, you should see that as a function of $a$ we have that $f(x(a), y(a))$ is concave down, meaning that the origin is a local maximum for this particular parabola through the origin.  If this point was genuinely a local min then all curves would agree about its local minimality at the origin.

Comment: Yes, I realised it after a little while trying to compute again the function! :D Thank you again!